# "he can move faster than Severus Snape confronted with shampoo when he wants to" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Well, who wouldn't want a nice little holiday after all the hard work he's been putting in?" asked Fred. "Point is, people, don't get lulled into a false sense of security, thinking (Voldemort)he's out of the country. Maybe he is, maybe he isn't, but the fact remains **he can move faster than Severus Snape confronted with shampoo when he wants to**, so don't count on him being a long way away if you're planning on taking any risks. I never thought I'd hear myself say it, but safety first!"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I don't understand "Severus Snape confronted with shampoo". It seems to be a metaphor or simile. How should we understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when I see a cat, I turn and run the other way—real fast. Cats terrify me.

"Severus Snape confronted with shampoo" is a *"resident joke"*. Severus Snape is known for his *"unkempt hair"*. See [Why did the best potions master have greasy hair?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144440/why-did-the-best-potions-master-have-greasy-hair)

I don't want to digress from the main issue by getting into why Snape does not like shampoo, or why he does not want to use them.

Sticking to English strictly, here is what I understand:

Fred is saying that when Snape is confronted with shampoo, he runs away unusually quickly. Snape bolts at the sight of shampoo. The speed at which he bolts is unusually fast for him. Fear/anger gets our adrenaline going—we move much faster than we usually do. Imagine how fast you would run if you are confronted by a Grizzly (no, you can't play dead).

> But [Voldemort can move even faster] than [Snape running away from shampoo.]

You can break down the original sentence into bits to understand it better.

> [ ... he (= Voldemort) can move faster] than [Severus Snape confronted with shampoo] when [he (= Voldemort) wants to ...]

This is essentially saying that Voldemort (at his equilibrium state) is much faster than a person running for their life.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. I wasn't aware of Snape's hair thing originally. Great explanation!